# Redirect in angularJS not working partially

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I'm having problems with redirect in angularJS.

For example it works perfectly fine, when the user logs in. If a user is logged in (information stored in the localstorage) it redirects him automatically to my '/dashboard'.

But when the user logs out it is not redirecting correctly but goes to 
'*http://localhost/ngJS/index.php#*' instead of anything else I tell him. What do I do wrong?

*ngJS* is my project-root-folder and *index.php* is just a container with my libraries and code-inclusions. I am running the sites on a local server *XAMMP*.

### mainAppMdl.js

```
var app = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);
/*
 * Configuration for redirecting
 * @param {type} $routeProvider
 */
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
     //WORKING
     .when('/', {resolve: {
                    "check": function ($location) {
                        if (localStorage.getItem('usr') && 
                                localStorage.getItem('usr') !== '0') {
                            $location.path('/dashboard');
                        }
                    }
                },templateUrl: 'pages/cover.html'
            })
    //WORKING LOADING THE CONTROLLER SUCCESSFULLY
    .when('/dashboard', {
                resolve: {
                    "check": function ($location) {
                        if (localStorage.getItem('usr') === '0') {
                            $location.path('/');
                        }}},
                templateUrl: 'pages/dummy.html',
                controller: 'logoutCtrl'
            })
    .when('/login', {
                templateUrl: 'pages/login/login.html',
                controller: 'loginCtrl'
            })
    .when('/logout', {redirectTo: '/'})
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
 }]);
```

### logoutCtrl

```
app.controller('logoutCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $log) 
{

        $log.log('logoutCtrl');
        $log.log($scope);
        $scope.message = $rootScope.message;

        $scope.logout = function () {
            if (typeof (localStorage) !== 'undefined') {
                localStorage.setItem('usr', 0);
                // NOT WORKING --------------------- redirect
                $location.path('/');
                // WORKING AND PRINTING ---------------------
                console.log('redirecting!');

            }
            /* No localstorage support */
            else {
                alert("Tut uns leid. Localstorage wird nicht unterstützt");
            }
        };

    });
```

### logout-template.php

```
<section class="bg-success text-info" id="horizontal-nav-pills" >
                <nav>
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#/new-report"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Bericht</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" ><a href="#" ng-click="logout();">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>                           
                </nav>
            </section> 
            <!--end horizontal-nav-pills-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="logout();">Logout</a>
```

use:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="logout();">Logout</a>
```

Comment: thanks that did it finally! Looking over it later I thought it was something with this link but didn't know what to change. And for styling purposes I needed an <a> element.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $scope.logout = function () {
        if (typeof (localStorage) !== 'undefined') {
            localStorage.setItem('usr', 0);
            // NOT WORKING --------------------- redirect
            $location.path('/');
            // WORKING AND PRINTING ---------------------
            console.log('redirecting!');

        }
        /* No localstorage support */
        else {
            alert("Tut uns leid. Localstorage wird nicht unterstützt");
        }
    };
```

The problem is with:

```
$location.path('/');
```

It should have been:

```
$location.path('/logout');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since neither `ngJS` nor `index.php` is in the code you posted I suppose that the problem comes from a different file that is currently not on your radar.

I suggest to get an editor that support's searching in mutliple files (like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) and search through the project directory for the above mentioned, two terms.

Comment: **ngJS** is just my root-folder-name.** Index.php** is just an empty container used by all my templates. I added the code, but I doubt there is a problem to be found in that.